# Как передать в функцию название элементов формы?

Tags: c#, функции, form, объекты, диаграммы

Хотел бы использовать универсальную функцию для вывода гистограммы. Т.е. вызывать функцию и отрисовывать гистограмму в chart1, либо в chart2.

Следовательно в функцию надо передать chart1 или chart 2 соответственно.
Помогите, как правильно передать название формы?

```
private void построитьГистограммуToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            //histo();

            //построить гистограму 
            buildHisto(bmp, chart1);
        }


        private void buildHisto(Bitmap bitmap, object sender)
        {
            var myChart = sender;
            // Сместить ось OY на влево (чтобы было видно 0 значения)
            //chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(-1, 0);
            myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = -1;
            myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        }
```

[image: Возникающая ошибка]

Comment: `sender` - это объект, которым может быть что угодно. В нем нет `ChartAreas` или чего то еще. Что бы из объекта сделать "нечто" - его надо в это "нечто" преобразовать, указать конкретно, что именно этот объект является именно этим типом. Делается это например простым `var myChart = (MyClass)sender;`. Но я не понимаю, зачем вам тут вообще передавать `object` в метод, зачем все это? Передавайте сразу ваше "нечто" и работайте с ним.

Comment: И как сразу  передать мое "нечто", а точнее chart1 и chart2, в зависимости от того, что мне нужно будет в конкретный момент?
object sender передавал, т.к. увидел похожее на другом сайте. Как правильно делать - пока не представляю

Comment: Какой у `chart1` и `chart2` тип? Вот его и используйте.

Comment: chart1 и chart2 — это элементы формы. Я не понимаю какой у них тип... @EvgeniyZ

Comment: Не за то вы взялись, если даже не можете узнать тип объекта, вам нужно учить самые основы. Хорошо, просто наведите на `chart1` (у строки `chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();`) и студая вам должна будет выдать что это за объект.

Comment: Спасибо!) Догнал и понял ошибку свою. 
Подключил: using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
и передал как 'Chart meChart'